# Empty or unknow structure in JNA

Tags: java, jna

Пишу обертку для Leap Motion в Java. dll подключаю через JNA. Пытаюсь реализовать код подключения к устройству, который выглядит примерно так на языке Си:

```
LEAP_CONNECTION connectionHandle = NULL;
LeapCreateConnection(NULL, &connectionHandle);
LeapOpenConnection(connectionHandle);
```

В описании про LEAP_CONNECTION сказано: "struct LEAP_CONNECTION - A handle to the Leap connection object." И собственно это все. Что за структура, что содержит, неизвестно и не понятно. Объект класса Structure отказывается создаваться без полей. При этом дальнейшая работа с connectionHandle как бы не нужна, эта переменная будет использоваться только в вызовах. На что можно заменить Structure? Пытался играться с классом Memory, но не совсем понимаю как можно заменить Structure.ByValue

Вот некоторые ссылки на документацию по Leap Motion:

- https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/v4/group___structs.html#struct_l_e_a_p___c_o_n_n_e_c_t_i_o_n
- https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/v4/callback-example.html#ExampleConnectionc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен объект класса [`PointerByReference`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/ptr/PointerByReference.html)

```
PointerByReference refConnection = new PointerByReference();
LeapCreateConnection(null, refConnection);
Pointer connectionHandle = refConnection.getValue();
LeapOpenConnection(connectionHandle);
```